# How to merge contents of jar in maven project

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

i have a maven project where there are 2 jars like A.jar and B.jar exist in source code. i would like to build the maven project so that C.jar should get generated which should contain contents of A.jar and B.jar. i am using below plugin but the C.jar doesn't contain all contents of both jar files.Can i skip the dependency tags for A.jar and B.jar files in pom.xml as these jars are part of source code?

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>DemoMavenBuildPlugins</groupId>
<artifactId>DemoMavenBuildPlugins</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DemoMavenBuildPlugins</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.princeton.cup</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-cup</artifactId>
        <version>10k</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>sampler.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/Demo</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>resources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/Demo/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.demo.tutorial.Demo</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <finalName>Demo/Demo</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please show the full content of your pom file ...best would be an example project on github or alike...

Comment: Hi Team, any idea?. in the above pom.xml, com.ibm.mq.jar and java-cup.jar should get extracted into another jar let us say result.jar through maven build

Comment: If you want to have a jar file which contains the dependencies this can be achieved either via maven-assembly-plugin or via maven-shade-plugin apart from that why do you use maven-dependency-plugin to copy something ? Does not really make sense..Also I don't understand the need for the maven-resources-plugin configuration? By default all resources from `src/main/resources` will being packaged into the resulting jar file If you like to filter them please take a look at the [configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Comment: Furthermore you are using extreme old versions of plugins as well as your java version is given with 7 which is extreme old ... I would recommend to use a more recent version of JDK etc.

Comment: Hi, I made below changes to pom.xml. added only maven-assembly-plugin plugin. still all dependencies are not extracted to resulting jar file.

Comment: <plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.10.1</version>
 <configuration>
  <source>1.8</source>
  <target>1.8</target>
 </configuration>
</plugin>